# Including ffmpeg with Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, ffmpeg, google-nativeclient

I'm trying to do something similare to [VideoStream](http://getvideostream.com/)

They include ffmpeg with [nacl](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client) and include it in a chrome app

I've beeen working on it, but I can't have the naclportlist ffmpeg working on my project !

The reasons are those

- nacl doesn't work with main() and command line, and ffmpeg requires it
- glibc, the only way to compile it, expect a main() ! Impossible to remove it (maybe with ppapi ?)

So my question is simple, how can I communicate with ffmpeg and chrome ? if VideoStream can do it, why can't I ?

Thanks a lot for yours answers !

Comment: there is a concept of "libavcodec" which is basically *you* manually using the underlying libraries FFmpeg does. HTH

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But is there any way to include the ffmpeg.c with the lib ? or do you I have to rewrite all the ffmpeg.c functions ?

Comment: you might be able to rename its main method and call it manually, I've wondered the same thing myself before, honestly...

Comment: I've just managed something with, But I'm having some issues with the "lrint" and 'lrintf' function : Do you know with what I can replace it ?

Comment: I'm looking into something similar and found out there is a version of ffmpeg that's bundled into chromium. Could be some hints there. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/third_party/ffmpeg/+/HEAD/chromium

Comment: I managed to compile webports with nacl now I am confused, what to do?! I am building a screen recorder using ffmpeg and nacl